# Error after uploading my angular 2 app to the server

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-cli

I have created an app using angular2-cli and angular RC.6.

I generated my app build for production and uploaded the files to my server.

Before uploading to my main website, I uploaded it to my `dev.mywebsite.com` development URL and the app worked great.

After I saw it works fine, I uploaded my app to my main website, www.mywebsite.com, and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.replace is not a function
```

Tried to refresh the cache, nothing seem to fix it. Why I get this error in my app runtime (loading) and how I can fix that?

Comment: can u check if 'e' is a string?

Comment: I don't even know what `e` is and where it comes from!